# Android Keeping Notification Alive

Tags: android, notifications

I want to issue a notification that stays in the status bar until I specifically issue a cancel from notification manager.  I know that there are some time fields for this, and I could of course provide an huge number for this, but i was wondering if there is a preferred way to specify this. Some way to indicate to the system that the notification is to be maintained until canceled, or is the millisecond measure the only way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FLAG_NO_CLEAR` with your `Notification`.

Comment: Are there some circumstances in which the notification will still get cleared?  I am also concerned about detecting if it is still there?  I suppose I could issue a cancel followed by a send on the notification id, I definitely do not want two of them showing up however....  If I use the same id and will it add more to the dropdown or just keep one?

Comment: @Androider: "Are there some circumstances in which the notification will still get cleared?" -- sure. At minimum, it will go away if your app is uninstalled. It probably also goes away if the user force-closes your app via the Settings > Applications screen. There may be other cases. "I am also concerned about detecting if it is still there?" -- you can't and don't need to. "If I use the same id and will it add more to the dropdown or just keep one?" -- there will only be one notification per app per id.